# Open File - All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or are not installed

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, default-applications, my-files

I can open my text editor (QuickEdit Pro) and then, within my text editor, navigate to any file I like and anything (.md or .sh or .pl) will open without trouble. But when I open the default 'My Files' app and navigate to some folder where I tap a .md file, I am faced with a plain white screen that contains nothing but the text in the title of this question. So far, .txt files stand out as being the only ones that can be directly opened in a text editor app.

I have installed 5 other random text editors and this white screen still pops up when I try to open a .md file directly.

What do I have to do to be able to tap a .md file and have it open in a text editor?

If my text editor is not configured to open anything besides .txt files, what would the developer have to do to fix this?

PS I'm running Android 6.0.1 on a Samsung Galaxy S5 Active.